# Xcode 9 - Warning on Location usage Description in Info.plist - iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, location, ios11, xcode9

I've just updated to Xcode 9.0 official version and when I run my app which uses Location service, it works fine but the console prints the following warning:

```
The app's Info.plist must contain both NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data
```

So I've tried to add the following key in my Info.plist:

```
 <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs your current location</string>
```

But when I try to run the app again Xcode 9 shows an alert that says: **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

So I switched back to:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
```

And the app works fine. Oh, and my Info.plist already contains the **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** key!

Is that a Xcode 9 bug in the console? Is anyone getting the same warning?

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I've fixed it by simply browsing and selecting the right **Privacy - Location usage** options in **Info.plist -> Open As -> Property List view**, here's the right keys to insert into Info.plist in case you need it:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs your current location</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs your current location</string>
```